# Difference between : and <> (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

### Context

Guys, i'm starting with Typescript and right now i'm just struggling with some concepts.

When specifying a parameter to a function, for example, i set the type like that:

```
function example(test: string){...}
```

But right now i'm getting into states and i see types being specified like that:

```
type User = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  avatar: string;
}

const [user, setUser] = useState<User>();
```

### Question

So my question is: What's the difference between **:** and **<>** ?

Comment: One is a type annotation, the other is a generic type parameter. They have nothing in common aside from being used in the type system.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for comming up with this new terms. Was able to do some research and now it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

```
function example(test: string){...}
```

This sets the type of a function parameter. If you call this function, you have to call it with `string` as its first argument.

---

```
const [user, setUser] = useState<User>();
```

This is a generic type parameter. This is a way to pass a type to some other other type for it to use in ways specific to that type. It may set the type a function argument, or it may do something completely different. In this case, it's declaring the type of the state that `useState` will manage. It sets the type of the default value (the argument you pass to `useState()`, the and the type returned value (`user` will be of type `User`, and `setUser()` will only accept a `User` as a value to set).

Comment: Thanks for the response. It really makes sense right now.